# How to filtering types by properties in JavaScript controller using the Alfresco Search WebScript?

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

For example, I have a type "Contract":

```
<type name="some-prefix:contract">
    <title>Contract</title>
    <parent>cm:content</parent>
    <mandatory-aspects>
        ...
        <aspect>some-prefix:resolution</aspect>
    </mandatory-aspects>
</type>
```

This type contains an aspect:

```
<aspect name="some-prefix:resolution">
    <title>Resolution</title>
    <properties>
        ...
        <property name="some-prefix:isCoordinated">
            <type>d:boolean</type>
            <default>false</default>
        </property>
    </properties>
</aspect>
```

By using this aspect, I set the state of the contract and trying to retrieve approptiate node:

```
...
getParameters : function Contract_getParameters() {
    var param = "term=";
    var query = "+TYPE:some-prefix\\:contract";
    if (this.widgets.filter.value == "inactive")
        query += " +@some-prefix\\:isCoordinated:false";
    else
        query += " +@some-prefix\\:isCoordinated:true";
    param += encodeURIComponent(query);
    return param;
},

getWebscriptUrl : function Contract_getWebscriptUrl() {
    return Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "slingshot/search";
},
...
```

If I use only this part, then I get the whole list of contracts:

```
var query = "+TYPE:some-prefix\\:contract";
```

But if I add an additional condition, for example:

```
query += " +@some-prefix\\:isCoordinated:true";
```

Then in this case I get an empty list.

By using the [Node Browser](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/adminconsole-nodebrowser.html) I found, that my query works:

```
+TYPE:some-prefix\:contract +@some-prefix\:isCoordinated:true
```

But when I call Alfresco Search WebScript from JavaScript controller I get the following:

```
{
    "totalRecords": 0,
    "totalRecordsUpper": 0,
    "startIndex": 0,
    "numberFound": 0,
    "facets":
    {
    },
   "highlighting":
   {
   },
    "items":
    [
    ],
    "spellcheck":
    {
    }
}
```

What could be the reason?..

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Martin Ehe](https://community.alfresco.com/people/mehe) gave an exhaustive answer: [How to filtering types by properties in JavaScript controller using the Alfresco Search WebScript?](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/231081-how-to-filtering-types-by-properties-in-javascript-controller-using-the-alfresco-search-webscript)

It solved my issue.

If use this query, the filter works:

```
...
getParameters : function Contract_getParameters() {
    var param = "query=";
    var query = "{\"datatype\":\"some-prefix:contract\",";
    if (this.widgets.filter.value == "inactive")
        query += "\"prop_some-prefix_isCoordinated\":\"false\"}";
    else
        query += "\"prop_some-prefix_isCoordinated\":\"true\"}";
    param += encodeURIComponent(query);

    return param;
},
...
```

In [this](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Alfresco-One-5x-Developers-Guide/blob/master/Chapter05/someco-client-extensions-project-ch5/share/src/main/amp/web/components/dashlets/whitepaper.js#L94) case, the filter is not working:

```
...
getParameters : function Whitepaper_getParameters() {
    var param = "term=";
    var query = "+TYPE:some-prefix\\:contract";
    if (this.widgets.filter.value == "inactive")
        query += " +some-prefix\\:isCoordinated:false";
    else
        query += " +some-prefix\\:isCoordinated:true";
    param += encodeURIComponent(query);
    return param;
},
...
```

..and be careful with [CMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) query: if you using the hyphen, then you should escape it:

```
some-prefix -> some_x002D_prefix
```

Otherwise you'll get an exception: `CMISQueryException: no viable alternative at character ...`